# Time Capsule showing monitor icon in Finder sidebar

Tags: macos, time-capsule

Normally my Time Capsule is seen in the Finder sidebar under "Shared" with an icon of a disk drive by the name of the Time Capsule. Now it keeps showing a monitor icon by the name of the Time Capsule, and when I click on it, it will change back to the disk drive icon.

I don't see any problems when I open Airport Utility and check the Time Capsule setup.  Anyone know why this is happening?

<sup>I'm using Mavericks, and a 3<sup>rd</sup>-gen Time Capsule</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Also I have this problem in `OS 10.10 Yosemite` and it's continues to give me the inconvenience, so I googled till I find the answer. Finally, I'm trying to do this: make sure that the TC is not mounted (or dismount it). Then 
in finder menu use `Go -> Connect to Server`. Type `AFP://TCnetworkname` or `IPaddress` (replace with the real IP or real network name). When the computer finds the TC, you need to give a password (public for default) type in your password if you changed it or public if not, then save it in your keychain. That's it.

Answer (score 0):

That's one of the bugs which Mavericks 10.9.4 has. So you can't do anything beside waiting and hoping, that apple will fix this issue in a future update. (by [c0dev](https://apple.stackexchange.com/users/59151/c0dev))